# Why is this loop only running once?

Tags: c++, while-loop, tinyxml

Why is this loop only running once?
noteDatabaseItem just takes a node and fills in the data. the xml has 3 notes in it.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<noteCollection>
  <note name="Test Note 1">This is test note 1 content!</note>
  <note name="Test Note 2">This is test note 2 content!</note>
  <note name="Test Note 3">This is test note 3 content!</note>
</noteCollection>
```

**C++:**

```
std::vector<notekeeper::noteDatabaseItem> noteList;
TiXmlElement* noteCollection = xmlDoc->FirstChildElement("noteCollection");
TiXmlElement* node = noteCollection->FirstChildElement("note");
int itemCount = 0;

while (node != NULL) {
    itemCount++;
    noteList.resize(itemCount);
    noteList.push_back(noteDatabaseItem(node));
    node = noteCollection->NextSiblingElement("note");
}
```

Comment: Why do you `resize` before you `push_back`? It resizes itself. Perhaps the last line should be `node = note->NextSiblingElement("note");`?

Comment: The XML loaded is above and there is 3 notes so there isn't 1, and the resize is a mistake thanks.

Comment: node = node->NextSiblingElement("note"); worked.

Comment: Hm, too bad I wasn't confident enough to make it an answer. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `node = node->NextSiblingElement("note")`?

`noteCollection` has only children, not siblings, right?

Answer (score 3):

You're getting the wrong element in your loop. Try this:

```
while (node != NULL) {
    itemCount++;
    noteList.push_back(noteDatabaseItem(node));
    node = node->NextSiblingElement("note");
}
```

The next sibling of the current node is the one you want. You were trying to get the next sibling of the parent node.

Answer (score 1):

```
node = noteCollection->NextSiblingElement("note");
```

is meant to be

```
node = node->NextSiblingElement("note");
```

Stupid mistake. Sibling not Child.

Comment: You should accept GoTo's answer, not re-post it. (i.e., delete this answer.)